# Passing shell output to a variable in Jenkins job

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins scripted pipeline job. I want to pass the output of docker inspect command to a variable. Then, I want to use that variable later in another steps.

Following is the command that will display the Mac-address. I want the output of this command to be stored in a variable.

`docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.MacAddress}}{{end}}' $INSTANCE_ID`

I have tried this but it didn’t worked for me.

```
  output = sh(
  returnStdout: true, 
  script: 'docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.MacAddress}}{{end}}' $INSTANCE_ID'
  )
```

Can anyone suggest me what is wrong in this or suggest me other ways to store the output in a variable.

Comment: Is there any error in the console output?

Comment: No error. It’s coming null when I am trying to echo the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using single quotes in the script and you're also wrapping it with single quotes, so Jenkins is running `docker inspect --format=` that should return nothing. Try wrapping the script with double quotes

```
output = sh(
  returnStdout: true, 
  script: "docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.MacAddress}}{{end}}' $INSTANCE_ID"
  )
```